# How to control data extension access permission for different users within the same Business Unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, permissions, dataextensions

I know In Shared Data Extensions, I can right click a folder and give permission to a business unit.

But within the same business unit, how can I assign different permissions to different users so they can only access certain data extension folders or data extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the SFMC roles and permission [guide](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/enterprise/enterprise_20_overview/roles/predefined_roles/) there is no way to restrict the permissions to access certain Data Extensions or certain folders.

However you can create [custom roles](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/enterprise/enterprise_20_overview/roles/custom_roles/) to restrict the users from accessing the Data Extensions completely. You can also manually check and uncheck the permissions box under **Admin > My Users**.

**References**

[- Custom roles](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/enterprise/enterprise_20_overview/roles/custom_roles/)

[- Mapping legacy for roles and permissions](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/enterprise/enterprise_20_overview/roles/mappings_for_legacy_roles_and_permissions/)